# Why can't Testcontainers find a table created with an init script?

Tags: postgresql, testcontainers

I try to access a table in a PostgreSQLContainer created by an init script during startup but Testcontainers says that he can't find the table. Why???

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "named_person")
@Data
public class NamedPerson {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8799954029578723024L;

    @Column(name = "xxx")
    private String xxx;
}
```

The test's base class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractApplicationIT {

    final static DockerImageName POSTGRES_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:13.2-alpine");

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(POSTGRES_IMAGE);

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

My test class:

```
@Transactional
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class NamedPersonIT extends AbstractApplicationIT {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.dbname}")
    private String dbName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.initScript}")
    private String initScript;

    @Autowired
    private NamedPersonRepository npr;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() {
        postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(POSTGRES_IMAGE)
                .withDatabaseName(dbName)
                .withUsername(username)
                .withPassword(password)
                .withInitScript(initScript);
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkDbContainerIsAlive() {
        assertThat(this.npr.findAll()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabelle "PERSON" nicht gefunden
Table "PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
select namedpe0_.id as id1_2_, namedpe0_.xxx as xxx2_2_ from person namedpe0_ [42102-200]
```

The initScript:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS named_person;
CREATE TABLE named_person (
  id                VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  xxx               VARCHAR(12)
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('1', 'abcdefg');
```

Comment: The error message is from H2, not from Postgres. So apparently there is a clash between the database where the init runs and the one you connect to

Comment: Unrelated but: I hope you don't use `varchar(36)` to store UUID values. For that you should declare the column with the type `uuid`